# onload() does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, encodeuricomponent

I'm using the below onload(). It works perfect on chrome and IE. But it doesn't work in FireFox. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te0j15ae/)

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML; 
var urlVar = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,"+ encodeURIComponent(myVar);
var newIm = new Image();

newIm.onload = function(){
   alert("works"); //doesn't work in FireFox
}
newIm.src = urlVar;
```

How can I make this work on Firefox as well?

Comment: This plugin is useful https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: @bunion thanks. But I'm looking to fix my code.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even in Chrome

Comment: It's not browser specific.  Check this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/qmzv23hb/

Comment: @VJS thanks. I guess the issue is somewhere in `urlVar`? I created the fiddle using IE. My fiddle works in IE but not in FF nor Chrome.

Comment: Why would an onload even be needed if you are giving the data directly to the image? You know the image will be ready as soon as you send it the urlVar string.

Comment: @2pha thanks. This is just a potion of my project. The onload() is essential. I just can't get passed this part. I need to solve this part to move forward.

Comment: @VJS in your fiddle, what is myVar used for, you call encodeURIComponent but do noghing with it, instead you load an image from the urlVar variable.

Comment: I think what we all need to know here is what exactly is expected to be in the myVar variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML; 
var urlVar = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,"+ encodeURIComponent(myVar);
var newIm = new Image();

function imagesLoaded() {
alert("works");
}  

newIm.onLoad=imagesLoaded();
newIm.src = urlVar;
```

It work for me in firfox.

This is a snap shoot for the code and how it work:

[image]

Also see the code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o335bm3k/1/)

Comment: How is this any different?

Comment: Dude, it is essentially the same.

Comment: You're assigning `undefined` to `newIm.onLoad`.

Comment: I know it's almost the same, but it works. Copy the code and try yourself to the see that it is work.@2pha

Comment: You need to assign a function to the onload property.

Comment: And what this code does ?  newIm.onLoad=imagesLoaded();

Comment: It assigns `undefined`.

Comment: Ahmed this only appears to be working because imagesLoaded() return value is being assigned to the onload and to do that your running imagesLoaded() early.

Comment: @bunion the function will not return value until the line newIm.onLoad=imagesLoaded(); is reached and to be sure, remove this line and check if the function will return a value or not.